# How to add DefaultAdress fields in Customer Sylius Form (symfony3)

Tags: forms, symfony, sylius

I think the title is not very clear, so I will explain better : 
I have edited the CustomerRegister form the add a few fields, and I would like to add DefaultAdress fields too (defaultAdress is a linked object to Customer - I have a getDefaultAdresse method in CustomerObject). I would like to add all the fields that are in the DefaultAddress object (street, country, etc.)

I don't know how to do that...

Do I need to modify the CustomerRegistrationTypeExtension to add fields for the address ? 
How can I call the fields in my twig file ? Like that : `{{ form_row(form.defaultAddress.street) }}` ?

I didn't find doc to explain that case.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: How are you passing in your Customer object to your twig file from your controller? Is it something like this: `return $this->render('mytwig.html.twig', array('customer' => $customer));` Can you show your code, so we can help you?

Comment: I don't have a controller, I extend the Sylius Entity Customer, the form Type CustomerRegistrationType with an Extension. I didn't foudn which controller is used by Sylius.

Comment: Your solution sounds good, did you try it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create `CustomerRegistrationTypeExtension`, just like you described. Inside of this extension, simply do:

```
use Sylius\Bundle\AddressingBundle\Form\Type\AddressType;

$builder->add('defaultAddress', AddressType::class)
```

Then override the template and you should be able to render the fields or entire form with:

```
{{ form_widget(form.defaultAddress) }}
```

I'd recommend using our standard address form template, by simply including it:

```
{% include '@SyliusShop/Common/Form/_address.html.twig' with {'form': form.defaultAddress} %}
```

Comment: Ah yes ! Very nice ! It works well ! I tried to add the defaultAddress, but I had the error "can't find getDefaultAddress method" or something like that. But I just see that I had added the add('defaultAdress') in the Sylius FormType directly instead of my FormExtension by inattention. Thks Pawel, and thks for your nice work on Sylius ! :)